Ubuntu 24.04 LTS keeps freezing (even when no program is running) [solved by upgrading bios version]
I own a (some years old) pc with Ubuntu 22; except for some driver problems, it has been working perfectly for months.
Recently I've run into a problem: after upgrading Ubuntu from version 22 to 24.04.02 (LTS), it started freezing even when there was no window open or any program was running.
Since then I've tried different solutions:

First of all, I've upgraded the kernel: I've read in other forums that this could have been the problem;
To be sure that it wasn't a hardware problem, I ran a MemTest but no error was reported.
I also tried a stress test over the CPU for 60 seconds: my pc passed without any problem.

Additionally, I've checked the RAM and swap usage: the first one is always under 2-3 GB (over 24), while the second one is 0. Depending on the task, CPU usage increases to 100% but the fans stay quiet, so I don't think this could be the cause (as said before, the pc stops even if no program is open).
One of the main suggestions was to check the log but I'm incapable of understanding what's written (sorry, I'm still learning how Ubuntu works and its language).
Let me know if additional information about my device is needed.
PS: Sorry if the text is poorly structured, English is not my first language.
Additional info | (Edit):

When pc freezes, the procedure Alt + Sys + REISUB doesn't work. It's necessary to force reboot manually. However, I'm sure that keyboard drivers are not the cause (since my PC froze while playing a video and the audio became distorted)
As suggested, here's the kernel version (in date 14/10/2024 [European format]): 6.11.0-061100-generic

Possible solution | (Edit):

I've upgraded the Bios version, hoping to fix the problem. I will edit this post in case of success or news.


I don't know the answer, but if it comes down to a kernel version, please update your post to show which kernel version (uname -r) you're running. It'll be useful for others.

For the guy asking for more info on my device:
My PC has the motherboard of the MSI H97 gaming 3 with a dual-core Intel Pentium, upgraded with 24 GB of RAM (ddr3).
If a bios upgrade didn't solve your issue, try the other solutions written in my post (they are based on most common suggestions); especially I suggest looking at your Kernel version: in most cases, it's what causes freezes. If this doesn't work either then you need to check the log for a crash report...
[I write this here cause its answer to my post disappeared getting deleted, I guess because it didn't respect conduct rules]
